# Maven Theme build Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, maven-3, maven-plugin, liferay-6

I am trying to build a theme with maven for Liferay.
I am able to build the theme as well but I would like to know more on below stuff

```
[INFO] --- liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.10.13:theme-merge (default) @ my-theme ---
[INFO] Parent theme group ID com.liferay.portal
[INFO] Parent theme artifact ID portal-web
[INFO] Parent theme version 6.2.10.14
[INFO] Parent theme ID _styled
[INFO] Copying html/themes/_unstyled/templates to C:\Dev\GIT_LOCAL_REPO\intranet\test-themes\my-theme\target\my-theme\templates
[INFO] Copying html/themes/_unstyled/css to C:\Dev\GIT_LOCAL_REPO\intranet\test-themes\my-theme\target\my-theme\css
[INFO] Copying html/themes/_unstyled/images to C:\Dev\GIT_LOCAL_REPO\intranet\test-themes\my-theme\target\my-theme\images
[INFO] Copying html/themes/_unstyled/js to C:\Dev\GIT_LOCAL_REPO\intranet\test-themes\my-theme\target\my-theme\js
[INFO] Copying html/themes/_styled/css to C:\Dev\GIT_LOCAL_REPO\intranet\test-themes\my-theme\target\my-theme\css
[INFO] Copying html/themes/_styled/images to C:\Dev\GIT_LOCAL_REPO\intranet\test-themes\my-theme\target\my-theme\images
```

**I would like to know from what location maven is trying to copy unstyle css ("html/themes/_unstyled/css" )stuff.**

**Where this path "html/themes/_unstyled/css" belong to?**

I am using _style as a base theme to develop my theme.

It is not using files from my server and neither the war present in my local maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that you are using 6.2.

The 6.2 plugins have a different approach they actually download the Liferay bundle or use a local one that you configure and load the files from there.

EDIT: 
This is for Liferay 7 
Liferay contains base theme _styled and _unstield. The _unstiled contains FTL templates but does not provide the base styling (css) that comes from styled.

If you use _styled as a base. The dependencies are loaded for styled and unstyled and they are applied as you can see in the log. The file should be stored in jar modules https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay/com.liferay.frontend.theme.unstyled and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay/com.liferay.frontend.theme.styled or in npm modules https://www.npmjs.com/package/liferay-frontend-theme-unstyled and https://www.npmjs.com/package/liferay-frontend-theme-styled

I'm not sure which one is used in maven. Gradle/npm build uses the npn packages.